# Bootstrap - modal sometimes breaks scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I load the page, a modal immediately is displayed. However, about half the time, it's impossible to scroll. I can see the scrollbar on the side of the window, but it doesn't let you scroll. Also, zooming the window into `150%` allows scrolling to work again.

How can I make it so the user can scroll up and down the modal? I'm using jQuery.

Comment: I have this problem and i solve it with giving the .modal-content height and overflow-y scroll

Comment: any working example?

Answer (score 0):

Modals will generally remove the scrollbar and male your page eesize due to the fact that when a modal is loaded, you normally overlay the body elements which remives and scrollbara, causing the body or wcreen width to adjust.